# how to create a table under another table in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Im new in crystal report. I already created the first table and wanted to create a new table under it, i try to create a new details section but its output was

1. First Row of table 1
2. First Row of table 2
3. Second Row of table 1
4. Second Row of table 2
5. Third Row of table 1
6. Third Row of table 2

Answer (score 0):

Take 3 sub reports one sub report for one table and place one by one in report header.

Comment: do i need to put the columnhead of the dataset on the subreport or exactly the dataset?

Comment: what is columnhead?